# The Ceylon Typechecker: How to obtain the typed syntax tree?

Tags: java, typechecking, ceylon

Im trying to programmatically use / embed the Ceylon Typechecker to analyse Ceylon source code. In this use case I want to access all the information that normally the compiler would consume. But Im not going to compile and Im not going to add dependency on the compiler.

It seem to me that the main.Main entry point in ceylon/typechecker/src/main/Main.java is not the appropriate entry point  for this use case (obtaining the typed tree and the attached models), because this information, which was collected by the visitors in the three checker passes is discarded, and only errors are printed.

So, my question is:

How can I parse and typecheck a compilation unit and then obtain 
1. the typed syntax tree, and
2. the associated model objects of the types the analysis visitors encounter in the tree, which are linked to from the tree.

edited:

There was (and is) some confusion on my side about the 3 different ASTs there are.

In the README in ceylon /ceylon.ast it is said:

¨ ... 
ceylon.ast.core – the Ceylon classes that represent a Ceylon AST. Pure Ceylon (backend-independent).
...
ceylon.ast.redhat – transforms a ceylon.ast.core AST from + to a RedHat compiler (ceylon-spec AST, and also contains functions to compile a ceylon.ast.core AST from a code string (using the RedHat compiler) 
... ¨.

So there are 3 ASTs: 1. The one generated by antlr, 2. ceylon.ast.core, and 3. ceylon.ast.redhat. 
Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, you'll want to:

- Configure a `TypeCheckerBuilder` with the source files you want to typecheck,
- Obtain a `TypeChecker` from the builder (`builder.typechecker`),
- Invoke the typechecker (`typeChecker.process()`),
- Process the results available from `typeChecker.phasedUnits`. Specifically, `typeChecker.getPhasedUnits().getPhasedUnits()` will give you a `List<PhasedUnit>`, and for each `PhasedUnit`, you can call `getCompilationUnit()` to obtain its `Tree.CompilationUnit`, which is the root of the AST. AST nodes also include getters for model objects.

For a detailed example, you can review the code for the Dart backend, working forwards and backwards from [the call to `process()`](https://github.com/jvasileff/ceylon-dart/blob/2d845a4783930eb1a827a50df6513fa719a1d4ac/ceylon-dart-compiler/source/com/vasileff/ceylon/dart/compiler/compile.ceylon#L355) in the `compileDart()` function.

See [testCompile](https://github.com/jvasileff/ceylon-dart/blob/2d845a4783930eb1a827a50df6513fa719a1d4ac/ceylon-dart-compiler/source/com/vasileff/ceylon/dart/compiler/testCompile.ceylon) for example code that calls `compileDart()`.

Comment: Ok, I added details to the final bullet. You are of course free to process the `Tree.CompilationUnit`s however you like: switch, visitor, or something else. You can also convert the Java based AST to a Ceylon based [`ceylon.ast`](https://herd.ceylon-lang.org/modules/ceylon.ast.core), as I have done for the Dart backend.